# Adding retry connection logic to ffmpeg(rtmp)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to create a video mosaic using ffmpeg. My full command looks like this -

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/output1 -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/output2 -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/output3 -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/output4 -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=640x480 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright]; [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft]; [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright]; [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=0 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=0:x=320 [tmp2]; [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=0:y=240 [tmp3]; [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=0:x=320:y=240"  -filter_complex amix=inputs=4:duration=longest  -c:a aac -strict -2 -ar 44100  -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/myStream
```

This works well as long as all 4 input streams are running. But say one of the stream drops for sometime and comes back online. The output continues to show this stream as stuck (paused). Because once the stream drops (AVERROR_EOF) `ffmpeg` stops trying to get more packets from the input stream. I have to restart the ffmpeg process to get back everything to work again.

Is there a way to add a retry logic here which will tell ffmpeg to keep trying to process all input sources as long as process is alive?

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution? Im trying to solve retry problem for single live stream